# Javascript: Failing to define node as a global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am learning some basic css/javascript animation and I am having trouble defining a global variable name for an HTML id. The script below works when the variable "circularthing" is called from within a function (as is shown), but when it is called from outside the function I cannot access the node through the variable name. This includes accessing the node directly through the console. I am able to define the variable from the console directly and have the function work interestingly enough.

```
var circularthing = window.document.getElementById('circularthing');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
    circularthing.style.top = event.y + 'px';
    circularthing.style.left = event.x + 'px';
});
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: is this script loaded before the element `id="circularthing"` appears in the source?

Comment: It depends on if you're running the JavaScript before or after the page load.  The event listener would most likely fire only after the page loaded, but the assignment for `circularthing` would fail if the DOM hadn't fully loaded yet.

Comment: if you change the name of the var to be different to the ID, you'll see it may not work

Comment: now that you mention it, the element would not be initialized when the variable is named (the javascript is in the head of the HTML document). Is there a way to define the variable after the whole document loads or should I include my script at the end of the body rather than the head

Comment: You can use `window.onload = function() {//do stuff when resources loaded}`